# Device won't go to login screen after removing gdm3

Tags: boot, 20.04, suspend, gdm

My Lenovo Legion laptop has Ubuntu 20.04 on it. My initial problem was that, when I boot up the laptop after it goes to sleep, the screen will remain black and I have to reboot to log in again.

I saw one of the solutions was to remove `gdm3`, so I ran the command:

```
apt remove gdm3
```

and rebooted.

Now the laptop freezes at the welcomie screen that is shown after you fire up the device.

[image: welcoming screen]

Any help would be appreciated as I really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu and lose all my data.

Comment: gdm3 is your greeter / display manager. It is the software that provides the GUI login functionality for your desktop environment. You will either need to reinstall the OS (easiest) or reboot into a recovery environment from GRUB to a root shell prompt with networking, and reinstall the software.  If you find some solution or guide online you should always understand what commands are going to do before you execute them.  If not, research before running commands that you do not know what they do.

Comment: If you keep good backups you never need to worry about data loss due to hardware failure or user error.  Even if you cannot rescue this installation you should still be able to mount your hard drives and access data from a live session

Comment: Try to press Esc and if you get a prompt, try logging in with your credentials and try installing gdm3 again. Then `reboot` and hope for the best.

Comment: Thank you @Nmath and @To Do, I managed to solve the problem easily by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, pressing that prompted me to log in so I logged in and installed gdm3 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, pressing that prompted me to log in so I logged in and installed gdm3 again and rebooted.